# Is there a way to use windows server backup with sharepoint 2013 and windows server 2012?

Tags: 2013, backup

I have a Windows Server 2012 installation with Sql Server 2012 and Sharepoint Server 2013.

Windows server backup worked fine before Sharepoint was installed.

After it was installed, windows server backup cannot back up system state because the VSS system writer is not available. 'vssadmin list writer' returns many writers but not the system writer. The event log shows:

```
Event ID 513

Cryptographic Services failed while processing the OnIdentity() call in the System Writer Object.
```

The problem is identical to this one:

http://weneversleep.com/2012/09/21/sharepoint-2013-preview-breaks-vss-system-writer/

I have not seen a working solution anywhere. Has anyone else experienced this or have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an issue specific to SharePoint 2013 preview.
Caused by a 'full stack issue'- basically too many sub directories in the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder.

These two posts might help you solve your issue:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734021(v=ws.10).aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/4458947a-623e-45c1-b8e4-868aad1e93b0/

Answer (score 0):

There are various solutions to this which includes:

1. Re-register VSS dll files
2. Simply restart the server
3. Run the command "Sc.exe sdset eventsystem
   D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)"
4. Replace the folder
   "HKLM\System\Currentcontrolset\Services\VSS\Diag\System Writer"
5. Install the Microsoft Hotfix KB2807849

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder C:\Windows\inf. Copy 3 files setupapi.ev1, setupapi.ev2 and setupapi.ev3 from a working server if these files are not present. Restart Cryptographic and Volume Shadow Copy service. Now run the command "Vssadmin list writers" and you will be able to see System Writers.

Answer (score 0):

Hi How to do replace this folder
Replace the folder "HKLM\System\Currentcontrolset\Services\VSS\Diag\System Writer"

Comment: I am afraid this does not provide an answer. You can consider asking your own question.